# Page does not load stylesheet or JS file in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have a page where i want to load a sytlesheet and a JS file for that particular page in worpress.

I have added the following code in the head section of where tabcontent.css is located in a directory called tabcontent-->template which is located as the same directory as my functions.php file and similarly for the js file.

`<link href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/tab-content/template1/tabcontent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

`<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/tab-content/tabcontent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

How can i get to load these files correctly.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. So, if your theme folder is xyz, is 'tabcontent.css' located at "xyz/tabcontent.css", "xyz/tab-content/tabcontent.css", "xyz/tab-content/template1/tabcontent.css" or "xyz/tab-content/template/tabcontent.css"?

Comment: @TomaszNguyen sorry should have been more clearer. It is xyz/tab-content/template1/tabcontent.css where xyz is my theme folder

Comment: It seems that the code you then use is fine. You could have otherwise a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri.

Comment: Regarding the js-file, did you use the correct path? So, no typos?

Comment: @TomaszNguyen thanks i checked again and there was a small typo in the directory name. Sorry to have wasted your time but appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to load js and css files for a specific page in WordPress. You'll want to use the is_page() conditional tag and use wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style() to load the assets. Here's an example:

```
<?php
    if( is_page(Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
    }
?>
```

This code should go in the functions.php file of your theme.
Please check out:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

It is very important to follow best practices when building a WordPress theme or plugin.